# Replacing HDD with SSD on laptop

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I own an Acer aspire E5-574g, which has a Western Digital WD10JPVX hard drive that is very slow. I am planning to upgrade to an SSD and keep the existing HDD as backup external drive.

**Western Digital WD10JPVX** is **9.5mm** while the SSD I am looking at is **KingSpec 128GB SSD 2.5" SATAIII with SMI2246XT controller 128gb solid state drive(ACSC2M128S25)** is **7mm**.

Will the thinner SSD work or would I need any additional accessories to have it fit?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work - as long as the drive is not bigger then the original drive it will mount fine without any additional accessories.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a [spacer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014LQM6I2) and add it to the 7mm SSD so that it fits to the 9.5mm HDD slot of you laptop

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have places where you can screw the drive it shouldn't be a problem for you to place it even if it's 7mm.

The size and the form factor do not matter when it comes to compatibility (unless we are talking about external drives and power requirements). As long as you have the same interface for the data and the power the drive should be fine (SATA connection). Mind that all SATA connections (SATAI, SATAII and SATAIII) are all compatible with each other.

Test the WD Blue with [WD Data Lifeguard Diagnostic](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=XAHhA1) and see if the drive's health is causing it to perform slow and if you need to back up your data ASAP.